# Dynamic class mixin in Django Views

Tags: python, django

I have a class based view that I need to inherit from another class if a site setting is set to true. I've done a fair bit of googling on python dynamic inheritance but haven't found anything that I could understand or that seemed appropriate. FYI: my python knowledge is far from extensive so this could be a very un-pythonic thing to do for all I know.

Here is some pseudocode to outline what I mean:

```
Class MyView(View):    
    If settings.IMPLEMENTS_ACTIVITY:
        Set MyView implements activity
```

I hope that helps explain what I mean. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class View1(View):
    pass

class View2(View1):        
   def sepcific_view2_activity(self):
       pass  

if settings.IMPLEMENTS_ACTIVITY:
  MyView = View1
else:
  MyView = View2
```

Comment: Not sure why you need the `type` there. Why not simply `MyView = View1` etc?

Comment: You are right, it's too complicated. Maybe stay with View1 and use MyView=View1 , and if settings key, MyView = type('View1',(),{'specific_method':func}).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather make a call to another class method than change inheritance:

```
Class MyView(View):    
    def get(request):
        If settings.IMPLEMENTS_ACTIVITY:
            return CoolView1().get(request)
        else:
            return CoolView2().get(request)


Class CoolView1(View):    
    def get(request):
        return 1


Class CoolView2(View):    
    def get(request):
        return 2
```